# Installing MYSQL on snow leopard problems

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to install mysql on snow leopard and having some problems.

I followed these steps in the hivelogic blog

http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard

all goes well but when i get to the final step i try to do

```
mysql -uroot
```

i get this

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: What is the output of the following command in the shell: ls /usr/local/mysql/bin ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superuser or serverfault?

Comment: i get

    innochecksum   mysql_fix_privilege_tables mysqld_multi
msql2mysql   mysql_install_db  mysqld_safe
my_print_defaults  mysql_secure_installation mysqldump
myisam_ftdump   mysql_setpermission  mysqldumpslow
myisamchk   mysql_tzinfo_to_sql  mysqlhotcopy
myisamlog   mysql_upgrade   mysqlimport
myisampack   mysql_waitpid   mysqlshow
mysql    mysql_zap   mysqlslap
mysql_client_test  mysqlaccess   mysqltest
mysql_config   mysqladmin   perror
mysql_convert_table_format mysqlbinlog   replace
mysql_find_rows   mysqlbug   resolve_stack_dump
mysql_fix_extensions  mysqlcheck   resolveip

Comment: I have it working the  "source ~/.profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Set the PATH

Did you do that (including the "source ~/.profile" bit)? Your shell cannot find the mysql command. So, you have either not installed it at all or installed in a location not listed in your PATH environment variable.

You can run a spotlight query from the command line to find all occurances of the mysql command like this:

```
$ mdfind mysql | grep '/mysql$'
```